# How to convert .bib generated by Mendeley for use with amsrefs

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, amsrefs

I'm using TeX live 2010. 
I have a .bib file generated from Mendeley, and 
I want to use that with amsrefs, but it's confusing and
the amsrefs documentation is somewhat hard to follow:
how do I massage the .bib file into something that
amsrefs can stomach. (I'm using amsart as the document class).

Comment: Did you sort this out in the end?

Comment: Haven't so far.

Comment: Does it not compile? Or is it just that the output is no good?

Comment: @Owen Maresh I think a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would be useful here.

Comment: the answer works for me - I used it on my own .bib file though.

Answer (score 4):

As the Mendeley-generated file should be a valid .bib file then using the `amsxport` package ([documentation on CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/amsrefs/doc/amsxport.pdf) or via `texdoc amsxport`) should be helpful. The process is also outlined in a [TUGboat article from 2000](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb21-3/tb68down.pdf).

For example the following simple document, processed by pdflatex and then bibtex,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsrefs}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{amsxport}
\bibliography{TeX_biblio}
\end{document}
```

will produce a .bbl file with the best-effort conversion of the specified bibliography file into amsrefs format (by default it will use the amsrn style).

Looking at the first couple of entries of the input .bib and output .bbl files:

```
@book{clark92,
    author = "Malcolm Clark",
    title = "A {\texttt{plain}} {\TeX} primer",
    year = "1992",
    edition = "1st",
    publisher = "Oxford",
    address = "Oxford, England"
}

@book{dalheimer08,
    author = {Matthias Kalle Dalheimer and Karsten G{\"u}nther},
    title = {{\LaTeX}---kurz \& gut},
    year = {2008},
    edition = {3},
    publisher = {O'Reilly},
    address = {K{\"o}ln, Deutchsland}
}
```

output:

```
\bib{clark92}{book}{
      author={Clark, Malcolm},
       title={A {\texttt{plain}} {\TeX} primer},
     edition={1},
   publisher={Oxford},
     address={Oxford, England},
        date={1992},
}

\bib{dalheimer08}{book}{
      author={Dalheimer, Matthias~Kalle},
      author={G{\"u}nther, Karsten},
       title={{\LaTeX}---kurz \& gut},
     edition={3},
   publisher={O'Reilly},
     address={K{\"o}ln, Deutchsland},
        date={2008},
}
```

Only a subset of .bib fields are supported and, of course, the output cannot be better than the input and will not initially have much of the added structure that amsrefs can support but should be a useful start.

Comment: I have encountered the same issue when importing a Mendeley library to be used with elsevier's harvard template.  could you suggest a solution?
the template file (elsarticle-harv.bst) suggests:
 ENTRY
  { address
    author
    booktitle
    chapter
    edition
    editor
    howpublished
    institution
    journal
    key
    month
    note
    number
    organization
    pages
    publisher
    school
    series
    title
    type
    url
    volume
    year
  }