# AMS formatting for bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I use Bibdesk to manage my bibliographic entries. I would like to put some entries in a paper and typeset them in the AMS format. I use BibLaTex, but this package doesn’t seem to have a preset for AMS style, so I would have to modify the style parameters myself, which seems like a daunting task. Otherwise I can use the `amsrefs` package. But to use `amsrefs`, you have to have your bibliography source file in a certain format that does not seem to be supported by Bibdesk. (You have to have entries starting with the `\bib` command, and for whatever reason Bibdesk does not seem to be able to produce a file in that format.)

So my question is, in short, how do I use AMS formatting while also using Bibdesk?

Comment: Perhaps the `amsxport` package can help. I believe it is meant to export from the traditional  `.bib` format to the `amsrefs` format. See, e.g., http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28123/8528

Comment: That did the trick. I appreciate it!